# How to listen to a series of modifications in a ViewModel without skipping an event?

Tags: android, listener, android-livedata

I have a `ViewModel` that has a list of items that a `RecyclerView.Adapter` uses.

When the user clicks on one of those items, one or more of the following things can happen:

- the item can be modified;
- another item(s) can be deleted.

I was using `LiveData` as a way to signal that an item of the list was being modified (more performatic than telling that the entire list was modified). But I was forgetting that `LiveData` can skip values.

Example:

```
// on background thread
mutableModificationEvent.postValue(ModificationEvent(...)) // will be skipped
mutableModificationEvent.postValue(ModificationEvent(...))
```

What is the most suitable way to do this job?

*I know that LiveData#setValue() exists. But since `#postValue` can skip values and be wrongly added to the code at some point, I'm discarding `LiveData` as an option.*

Comment: I've experienced LiveData skipping values but only when receiving too many updates in a very short space of time (milliseconds). I would have thought that wouldn't be a problem if the only updates it's getting would be as a result of user interaction?

Comment: How about batching them and post a `List<ModificationEvent>`? Of course this would need some kind of syncing, cleaning the previous list, adding new items to the list, and at some point update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use one of the reactive streams such as in RxJava or Kotlin Coroutines. Here is an example of kotlin flow ([taken from here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow#create)):

```
val latestNews: Flow<List<ArticleHeadline>> = flow {
    while(true) {
        val latestNews = newsApi.fetchLatestNews()
        emit(latestNews) // Emits the result of the request to the flow
        delay(refreshIntervalMs) // Suspends the coroutine for some time
    }
}
```

Here is an example of using flow with transforming it to LiveData ([link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata)):

```
val user: LiveData<User> = liveData {
  val data = database.loadUser() // loadUser is a suspend function.
  emit(data)
}
```

I have not tried this but it looks like the flow above should emit items one by one and no items should be skipped.